# Deriving ECDSA Public Key from Private Key

Tags: java, cryptography, bouncycastle, ecdsa

I was attempting to generate a public ECDSA key from a private key, and I haven't managed to find much help on the internet as to how to do this. Pretty much everything is for generating a public key from a public key spec, and I don't know how to get that. So far, this is what I've put together:

```
public void setPublic() throws GeneralSecurityException {
    ECNamedCurveParameterSpec params = ECNamedCurveTable.getParameterSpec("secp256k1");
    KeyFactory fact = KeyFactory.getInstance("ECDSA", "BC");
    ECCurve curve = params.getCurve();
    java.security.spec.EllipticCurve ellipticCurve = EC5Util.convertCurve(curve, params.getSeed());
    java.security.spec.ECPoint point = ECPointUtil.decodePoint(ellipticCurve, this.privateKey.getEncoded());
    java.security.spec.ECParameterSpec params2=EC5Util.convertSpec(ellipticCurve, params);
    java.security.spec.ECPublicKeySpec keySpec = new java.security.spec.ECPublicKeySpec(point,params2);
    this.publicKey = fact.generatePublic(keySpec);
}
```

However, when running, I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid point encoding 0x30
at org.bouncycastle.math.ec.ECCurve.decodePoint(Unknown Source)
at org.bouncycastle.jce.ECPointUtil.decodePoint(Unknown Source)
at Wallet.Wallet.setPublic(Wallet.java:125)
```

What am I doing wrong? Is there a better/easier way to do this?

EDIT: I've managed to get some code to compile, but it does not work correctly:

```
public void setPublic() throws GeneralSecurityException {
    BigInteger privKey = new BigInteger(getHex(privateKey.getEncoded()),16);
    X9ECParameters ecp = SECNamedCurves.getByName("secp256k1");
    ECPoint curvePt = ecp.getG().multiply(privKey);
    BigInteger x = curvePt.getX().toBigInteger();
    BigInteger y = curvePt.getY().toBigInteger();
    byte[] xBytes = removeSignByte(x.toByteArray());
    byte[] yBytes = removeSignByte(y.toByteArray());
    byte[] pubKeyBytes = new byte[65];
    pubKeyBytes[0] = new Byte("04");
    System.arraycopy(xBytes, 0, pubKeyBytes, 1, xBytes.length);
    System.arraycopy(yBytes, 0, pubKeyBytes, 33, xBytes.length);




    ECNamedCurveParameterSpec params = ECNamedCurveTable.getParameterSpec("secp256k1");
    KeyFactory fact = KeyFactory.getInstance("ECDSA", "BC");
    ECCurve curve = params.getCurve();
    java.security.spec.EllipticCurve ellipticCurve = EC5Util.convertCurve(curve, params.getSeed());
    java.security.spec.ECPoint point = ECPointUtil.decodePoint(ellipticCurve, pubKeyBytes);
    java.security.spec.ECParameterSpec params2 = EC5Util.convertSpec(ellipticCurve, params);
    java.security.spec.ECPublicKeySpec keySpec = new java.security.spec.ECPublicKeySpec(point,params2);
    this.publicKey = fact.generatePublic(keySpec);
}

private byte[] removeSignByte(byte[] arr)
{
    if(arr.length==33)
    {
        byte[] newArr = new byte[32];
        System.arraycopy(arr, 1, newArr, 0, newArr.length);
        return newArr;
    }
    return arr;
}
```

When I run it, it generates a publicKey, but it's not the same one that the private key corresponds to.

Comment: I assume you have read [this](http://www.bouncycastle.org/wiki/display/JA1/Elliptic+Curve+Key+Pair+Generation+and+Key+Factories).

Comment: @DevilsHnd that explains how to generate a Public key from a PublicKeySpec, and the rest of the examples it gives, from what I saw, are generation of a new, random key. I need to recover an existing keypair from an inputted private key in my case.

Comment: Perhaps changing the title of the question to "Deriving ECDSA Public Key" would be clearer

Comment: There are multiple ways of encoding a public key: you can have an ASN.1 / DER encoded representation, which usually starts with an ASN.1 SEQUENCE byte (0x30) and containns things such as the object identifier identifying the key type / parameters. Or you could have a flat (uncompressed) point format that starts with 04 (not to be confused with the value 0x04 used to encode an ASN.1 OCTET STRING). So you're likely just receiving different encodings.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes Either way, I assume that BouncyCastle has a consistent output format for the code I have, so there's no way for me to be receiving different encodings unless the libary has some issues.

Comment: Maybe so, but in the first code segment you even think that the private key consists of a point, which is doesn't. The encoding of the private key consist of a SEQUENCE with many elements; trying to parse that as point is of course nonsense. `removeSignByte` is also not complete: the coordinates x and y could also be smaller than 32 bytes (try and look up I2OSP function also used for RSA). That said, the code should work if normalized. Anyway, you assume a lot, but I'm glad you've got something working now.

Comment: Maybe what you are missing is... The ECDSA private key is a random *integer*. It is usually denoted as `x` in the libraries I work with. The public key is `G ^ x`, where `G` is the base *point*. So exponentiating a point by and integer results in a point. The resulting point from `y = G ^ x` is your public key. The other part you are probably missing is, exponentiation in the group is multiplication (all groups have two operations; usually addition and multiplication). So look for an `exponentiate(...)` or `multiply(...)` method. Share `y`, keep `x` private.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

So after a while, I figured out a solution and decided to post it in case anyone else has the same issue as me:

```
KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("ECDSA", "BC");
    ECParameterSpec ecSpec = ECNamedCurveTable.getParameterSpec("secp256k1");

    ECPoint Q = ecSpec.getG().multiply(((org.bouncycastle.jce.interfaces.ECPrivateKey) this.privateKey).getD());

    ECPublicKeySpec pubSpec = new ECPublicKeySpec(Q, ecSpec);
    PublicKey publicKeyGenerated = keyFactory.generatePublic(pubSpec);
    this.publicKey = publicKeyGenerated;
```

EDIT: Removed the code decoding the ECPoint as per @MaartenBodewes comment.

Comment: You should be able to use `Q` directly instead of `point`. If this fails, add a method call `normalize()` to the end of the calculation.

Answer (score 4):

Building on the previous answer one can extend this to the case that all one is given is a private key satisfying BCECPrivateKey interface:

```
DerivePubKeyFromPrivKey(BCECPrivateKey definingKey, Provider provider) {

    KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("EC", provider);

    BigInteger d = definingKey.getD();
    org.bouncycastle.jce.spec.ECParameterSpec ecSpec = 
    definingKey.getParameters();
    ECPoint Q = definingKey.getParameters().getG().multiply(d);

    org.bouncycastle.jce.spec.ECPublicKeySpec pubSpec = new 
    org.bouncycastle.jce.spec.ECPublicKeySpec(Q, ecSpec);
    PublicKey publicKeyGenerated = keyFactory.generatePublic(pubSpec);
    return publicKeyGenerated;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I came here with the same problem in Kotlin, so, in case it helps anyone, here's how I derived the `PublicKey` from an ECDSA `PrivateKey` in Kotlin. This code is based on [Lev Knoblock's Java answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49211667/1424877) and then trial-and-errored until it worked.

In my case I knew that my key used the `secp256k1` curve, so I could hard-code that part. I didn't bother to learn how to generalize it to other curves.

```
import java.security.KeyFactory
import java.security.KeyPair
import java.security.PrivateKey
import java.security.PublicKey
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.pkcs.PrivateKeyInfo
import org.bouncycastle.jce.ECNamedCurveTable
import org.bouncycastle.jce.interfaces.ECPrivateKey
import org.bouncycastle.jce.spec.ECNamedCurveParameterSpec
import org.bouncycastle.jce.spec.ECPublicKeySpec
import org.bouncycastle.math.ec.ECPoint
import org.bouncycastle.openssl.jcajce.JcaPEMKeyConverter
import org.bouncycastle.openssl.PEMParser

fun getECPrivateKeyFromPEM(privatePem: String): ECPrivateKey {
    val pemParser = PEMParser(privatePem.reader())
    val privateKeyInfo = pemParser.readObject() as PrivateKeyInfo
    return JcaPEMKeyConverter().getPrivateKey(privateKeyInfo) as ECPrivateKey
}

fun getKeyPairFromECPrivateKey(privateKey: ECPrivateKey): KeyPair {
    val keyFactory: KeyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("ECDSA", "BC")
    val spec: ECNamedCurveParameterSpec = ECNamedCurveTable.getParameterSpec("secp256k1")
    val Q: ECPoint = spec.getG().multiply(privateKey.getD())
    val publicKey: PublicKey = keyFactory.generatePublic(ECPublicKeySpec(Q, spec))
    return KeyPair(publicKey, privateKey)
}
```

And here's my test harness:

```
import java.io.StringWriter
import org.bouncycastle.openssl.jcajce.JcaPEMWriter

fun main() {
    val privatePem = """
       |-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
       |MIGHAgEAMBMGByqGSM49AgEGCCqGSM49AwEHBG0wawIBAQQg55EMdhNJX+YN/bjN
       |Eof91oKqEqD0QidEsRMhHBwSRjShRANCAARnSFpE0LDugORBWlSJz0Zf9e0mR9s6
       |tlxSeo1Nbd2vv9LDedm+l/CfZpbyYvPm49DAKDhkUHFIVDd2SsiPrRa7
       |-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
    """.trimMargin()
    val privateKey: ECPrivateKey = getECPrivateKeyFromPEM(privatePem)
    val pair: KeyPair = getKeyPairFromECPrivateKey(privateKey)
    val pems: String = StringWriter().use {
        val pemWriter = JcaPEMWriter(it)
        pemWriter.writeObject(pair.getPublic())
        pemWriter.writeObject(pair.getPrivate())
        pemWriter.flush()
        it.toString()
    }
    println(pems)
}
```

This prints out:

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MFYwEAYHKoZIzj0CAQYFK4EEAAoDQgAEcE4HMAHLDvPr6xHKsjhPXJzTdxLlRRR8
BfYnI2TGb0QLTFyyXm13CeYiLnxbkGhSvz9ZRo0zGQygKPVpgiThSw==
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
-----BEGIN EC PRIVATE KEY-----
MHcCAQEEIOeRDHYTSV/mDf24zRKH/daCqhKg9EInRLETIRwcEkY0oAoGCCqGSM49
AwEHoUQDQgAEZ0haRNCw7oDkQVpUic9GX/XtJkfbOrZcUnqNTW3dr7/Sw3nZvpfw
n2aW8mLz5uPQwCg4ZFBxSFQ3dkrIj60Wuw==
-----END EC PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Comment: hey there! could you give me a hand to  encrypt/decrypt. using private/public pem files?